NWConnection Always Fails on Physical iPhone but Works on Simulator
When I was attempting to establish a TCP connection using NWConnection on a physical iPhone, the connection consistently fails with the error:
connection did change state, new: waiting(POSIXErrorCode(rawValue: 50): Network is down)
connection did change state, new: preparing
connection did change state, new: waiting(POSIXErrorCode(rawValue: 50): Network is down)
However, when running the same code in the iOS Simulator, the connection succeeds without issues.

However, when running the same code in the iOS Simulator, the connection succeeds without issues.
I have configured the Info.plist file with the key:
NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription
Here is my code:
func start() -> NWConnection {
   let myHost: NWEndpoint.Host = "192.168.1.154"   // My MacBook
   let myPort: NWEndpoint.Port = 1234
   let connection = NWConnection(to: .hostPort(host: myHost, port: myPort), using: .tcp)
   connection.stateUpdateHandler = { newState in
      print("connection did change state, new: \(newState)")
   }
   connection.start(queue: .main)
   return connection
}

Here’s the process:
1. Upon the first installation of the app, executing NWConnection.start() triggers the prompt: “Allow [App Name] to find devices on the local network”.
2. After selecting “Allow,” the app receives the error: waiting(POSIXErrorCode(rawValue: 50): Network is down).
3. Using an RVI packet trace reveals no traffic from the iPhone.
4. Restarting the app, device, and server yields the same result.
5. Clean project, build and run the app without modifying any code also yields the same result.
6. Adding a new line in a comment (no functional code changes), build and run the app allows it to connect successfully.
7. Restarting the app, device, and server after this also works, and the app continues to connect successfully.
8. Using an RVI packet trace after this shows data being exchanged between 192.168.1.154 and 192.168.1.157.

Development environment:
Xcode 15.3
MacOS 14.4.1
Device OS: iOS 18.1

This is my first time working with the Network Framework, any hints or suggestions would be appreciated!
